# JS changes width of tbody?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an table in my HTMl view (php mvc).
The table displays some basic information in a row.
By clicking the 'More' botton (+) you can see other information belonging to this user.

But somehow activating the JS chances the width of the affected row and the rows below, and slightly the first row.
How is this possible? And how can I prevent this?

Any help is welcome.

The code is in a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/jdkosnl/e71ms5ar/41/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-more-button').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var forId = $(this).data('more-for');
        var $showMoreElement = $(this).closest('table').children('.show-more[data-more-id="' + forId + '"]');
        if ($this.hasClass('fa-plus-square')) {
            $this.removeClass('fa-plus-square').addClass('fa-minus-square');
            $showMoreElement.css('display', 'block');
        } else if ($this.hasClass('fa-minus-square')) {
            $this.removeClass('fa-minus-square').addClass('fa-plus-square');
            $showMoreElement.css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using `display: block` when working with tables and their elements. The suitable value for `tbody` is '[table-row-group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)' (instead of 'block'). Like this:

```
if ($this.hasClass('fa-plus-square')) {
  $this.removeClass('fa-plus-square').addClass('fa-minus-square');
  $showMoreElement.css('display', 'table-row-group');
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye6b01sz/).